# I commited my work to the wrong branch on Git

Tags: git

After finished working on code and confirmed everything is okay i did `git add *`. After that i did `git commit -m (added my commit mesage)`, which committed to branch1.

After that i did `git branch branch2`, then `git checkout branch2`, then `git push origin branch2`. Is there a problem in doing so as i now have 2 branches pointing to the same commit?

Comment: you can revert your commit. git reset <commitcode>

Comment: Can you explain what happened, like if there is no danger in what i did plus the changes are pushed already i am able to see it on my repository but i just dont understand like why one can or cant do that?  I see the new branch i created before commiting does have the same work so it seems a bit pointless to redo it again

Comment: Less paraphrasing, more code. I have no idea what you did.

Comment: There nothing wrong with my code, i was working on my repo on a branch lets call it branch1 i commited my work on branch one but before pushing the work i created branch2 and then did a "git push origin ......mywok" 

The correct way was to create branch2 commit my work to branch2 and push it.

Comment: What do you mean by "I committed my work on branch one"? What do you mean by "I created branch2"? What commands did you use? What is `mywok`? Where are you pushing to?

Comment: after finished working on code and confirmed everything is okay i did "git add *"
After that i did "git commit -m (added my commit mesage)" --> which commited to branch1
After that i did "git branch branch2"
Then "git checkout branch2"
then "git push origin branch2"

Sorry im brand new to all this

Comment: Side note: I would recommend `git add .` over `git add *` as the latter can bypass gitignore.

Comment: `git branch foo; git checkout foo` can be combined into `git checkout -b foo`.

Answer (score 0):

> So I committed my work to the wrong branch as stated but after that, I did a git branch, created the right branch and pushed the same work to that. My question is what exactly has happened.

You have two branches pointing to the same commit.

> Like will it submit to both branches, will it update my old branch with the new content.

The branches are independent of each other. When you create new commits in one of the two branches, the other won't follow.

> Because most people who committed to the wrong branch but not pushed yet, I have seen there is a way to revert but I committed and pushed to 2 different branches

If some people committed to the wrong branch and not pushed yet, tell them to fetch the good branch, then rebase/cherry-pick their commits on top of the good branch, and push. After everything is cleaned up, delete the wrong branch.

Comment: yes i have 2 branches pointing to the same commit, that's right. Is that a problem?